# What is correlation in nlme package

Tags: r, statistics

Could someone tell me what is this result when you apply mixed model with lme

I understand the first part but what is the second part wants to tell us (Correlation): Are they the correlation with intercept?

```
Fixed effects: Ratio ~ ADF + CP + FCM + DMI + DIM 
                 Value  Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  3.1199808 0.16237303 158 19.214896  0.0000
ADF         -0.0265626 0.00406990 158 -6.526603  0.0000
CP          -0.0534021 0.00539108 158 -9.905636  0.0000
FCM         -0.0149314 0.00353524 158 -4.223598  0.0000
DMI          0.0072318 0.00498779 158  1.449894  0.1491
DIM         -0.0008994 0.00019408 158 -4.634076  0.0000

Correlation: 
    (Intr) ADF    CP     FCM    DMI   
ADF -0.628                            
CP  -0.515  0.089                     
FCM -0.299  0.269 -0.203              
DMI -0.229 -0.145  0.083 -0.624       
DIM -0.113  0.127 -0.061  0.010 -0.047
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As I answered in the comments of your other question:)

These are the correlations among the fixed effect estimates. If they are very high (e.g. absolute value > 0.9), they may indicate possible problems with the stability of the estimate (because you are fitting predictors with strongly collinear effects). I would say in general that if they're less than that it's pretty safe to ignore them. If they are higher, you *might* want to consider leaving out some predictors, or reducing the dimensionality of the model somehow (e.g. by PCA on the predictors -- Frank Harrell's *Regression modeling strategies* book is a good source), but be careful about data snooping. This [r-sig-mixed-models mailing list thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2009q1/001921.html) gives more information.

(This is bordering on a CrossValidated [statistics] rather than StackOverflow [programming] question ...)

Comment: Hi Ben, I understand the problem of co-linearity but I am wondered why this values of correlation are different from what I got using cor.test (Pearson correlation)?
For example: Correlation between DMI vs FCM obtained by cor.test is 0.65 but in the aobe output it is 0.62. The same pattern for other variables>